# Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, to find its inverse near a given point

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a function given by
$$f\left(x,y\right)=\left(x-y,xy\right),\,\, \left(x,y\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2$$
**Question :** What is the inverse of $f$ near the point $\left(2,-3\right)$?

Upon checking the conditions, *inverse function theorem* gives me the existence of $f^{-1}$, that $f^{-1}$ is $C^1$ under appropriate condition and an explicit form of the derivative of $f^{-1}$. However, I do not understand how to calculate an explicit form of $f^{-1}$ using *inverse function theorem*.

By direct calculation, I find :
$$f^{-1}\left(u,v\right)=\left(\frac{2v}{-u\pm\sqrt{u^2+4v}},\frac{-u\pm\sqrt{u^2+4v}}{2}\right)$$
**Two issues :** $1$. It appears to be a one-to-two(!) map.

$2$. At the point $\left(2,-3\right)$, both the arguments are complex numbers!

**Any help would be much appreciated.**

Comment: The inverse function theorem does not "compute" $f^{-1}$ for you. Instead it guarantees the existence (locally, and under precise assumptions) of an $f^{-1}\in C^1$ even in cases where you are not able to produce explicit formulas through algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $f(2,-3)=(5,-6)$, hence $f^{-1}(5,-6)=(2,-3)$. Now compute $f^{-1}(5,-6)$ with

$f^{-1}\left(u,v\right)=\left(\frac{2v}{-u\pm\sqrt{u^2+4v}},\frac{u\pm\sqrt{u^2+4v}}{2}\right)$ and you will see which sign $ \pm$ is valid !

Comment: With $-$ sign, I'm getting the desired result. Just a question : Do we really need the inverse function theorem here (to show existence)? Or direct computation suffices?

Comment: @Eugenia Direct (careful) computation shows that this is an inverse function somewhere, and substitution can verify that this is an inverse at $(2,-3)$, but does not make any statements about where else this inverse relationship holds, if anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Attempt : $f^{-1}$ near $f(2,-3)$.

$a= x-y$; $b=xy;$

$a^2+4b =(x+y)^2;$

$x+y = -\sqrt{a^2+4b}$ (why minus ?)

$a=x-y$;

$2x= a-\sqrt{a^2+4b};$

$2y= -a-\sqrt{a^2+4b};$

Check:

$x-y=a$; $xy=-(1/4)(a^2-(a^2+4b))=b$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a small error. $f(2,-3)=(2-(-3),2\times(-3)) = (5,-6)$. $\sqrt{u^2 + 4v}\Big|_{(u,v) = (5,-6)} = \sqrt{25-24} = 1$. So the possible inverses for the point $(5,-6)$ are

$$f^{-1}(5,-6) =\left(\frac{-12}{-5\pm1},\frac{-5\pm1}{2}\right) $$
Since we want this to be $(2,-3)$, we are forced to pick the signs
$$(2,-3) = f^{-1}(5,-6) =\left(\frac{-12}{-5-1},\frac{-5-1}{2}\right) $$

Comment: I understood your point. I have a little confusion. It clearly gives us an inverse function that maps $\left(5,-6\right)$ to $\left(2,-3\right)$. However, I'm required to find an inverse *around* the point $\left(2,-3\right)$. My question : Is direct computation enough? Or do I need to check conditions of inverse function theorem to confirm an open set around $\left(2,-3\right)$?

Comment: @Eugenia Both maps are inverses. We have two inverses essentially because $xy = (-x)(-y)$ in the second coordinate, but they are nice continuous / differentiable / smooth where they are defined, and one of them passes through the point in the question, so that's the one you want. Inverse function theorem tells you that this is the unique inverse that does this.